# Turning an ordered list into a table

Tags: javascript

Still pretty new at JavaScript. I'm trying to write a program where you replace an ordered list with a table. The table should have 2 columns and 3 rows. The first column has the numbers(1,2,3) and the right column has the names of the games. How do I get the table to replace the list and read the list items?

Here is the JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/gmpc0acd/74/

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table,td
{
  border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Top Games</p>
<ol id="list">
<li id="element1">Halo</li>
<li id="element2">Portal</li>
</ol> 

<button onclick="addNewGame(); this.disabled=true">Insert</button>
<button onclick="tableCreate()">Replace</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function addNewGame() {
  let ol = document.getElementById("list");
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Rocket League"));
  ol.appendChild(li);
  list.insertBefore(li,list.childNodes[2]);
}

function tableCreate()
{
 var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
    x.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
    document.body.appendChild(x);

    var y = document.createElement("TR");
    y.setAttribute("id", "myTr");
    document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(y);

    var z = document.createElement("TD");
    var t = document.createTextNode("want game names in here");
    z.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("myTr").appendChild(z);
}
```

Comment: What's your question? How does your code go wrong? Any thoughts on what you think you need to do instead?

Comment: Exactly. I have no idea why my code creates a new table instead of replacing the previous element which is the list.

I also don't know how to get it to read the list Items.

Comment: `document.createElement` creates a new table.. you had to use `getElementById` or something to get the existing one.

Comment: Well for starters, you won't do much replacement when you are calling `document.createElement` and `.append`

Comment: I've tried that in another iteration of this problem and I also can't seem to get it to work. Have been looking for examples to try to build my code but can't find much that actually helps. I'm very stumped on this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: so basically you want to replace the list or to replace the current table? looking at your fiddle, i don't get it, what insert and replace button should do.

Comment: Insert adds a game to the current List. Once Insert is used, replace is then pressed to turn that new list into a table.

In the end there should only be a table left and the list should disappear but it's contents would be moved to the table.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a div 'id' - 'tryme' and inside i got the list.
so when you click 'replace' it should clear the div using innerHtml and then build the table. ( appending the 'tryme' div )
**edited**
To get 'ol' children use
let elmList = document.getElementById('list').children;
now you can iterate it like an array and use its 'innerText'/'innerHtml' as you like.
In my example before clearing 'tryme' i have an array with the lists children.
as displayed in the console.

```
 let trymeDiv = document.getElementById("tryme");
    trymeDiv.innerHTML = "";

    var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
    x.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
    document.getElementById('tryme').appendChild(x)

  <p>Top Games</p>
<div id="tryme">
    <ol id="list">
        <li id="element1">Halo</li>
        <li id="element2">Portal</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        table,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <p>Top Games</p>
    <div id="tryme">
        <ol id="list">
            <li id="element1">Halo</li>
            <li id="element2">Portal</li>
        </ol>
    </div>


    <button onclick="addNewGame(); this.disabled=true">Insert</button>
    <button onclick="tableCreate()">Replace</button>
</body>

</html>
<script>
    function addNewGame() {
        let ol = document.getElementById("list");
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Rocket League"));
        ol.appendChild(li);
        list.insertBefore(li, list.childNodes[2]);
    }

    function tableCreate() {
        let elmList = document.getElementById('list').children;
        arrayOfGames = [];
        for ( var i = 0; i < elmList.length; i++){
            arrayOfGames.push(elmList[i].innerText);
        }
        console.log(arrayOfGames);
        let trymeDiv = document.getElementById("tryme");
        trymeDiv.innerHTML = "";

        var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
        x.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
        document.getElementById('tryme').appendChild(x);

        var y = document.createElement("TR");
        y.setAttribute("id", "myTr");
        document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(y);

        var z = document.createElement("TD");
        var t = document.createTextNode("want game names in here");
        z.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById("myTr").appendChild(z);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Oh I see how to replace it. Thank you for that. I can't believe I couldn't think of that.  I was wondering how would I go about changing the cells to show the list items?